# How can I validate a file upload field in TYPO3?

Tags: validation, file-upload, typo3, fluid, extbase

I want to validate a file input field in TYPO3 but it seems that NotEmpty annonation not work on a property of type filereference:

```
/**
 * image
 * 
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $image;

/**
 * Returns the image
 * 
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
 */
public function getImage() {
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Sets the image
 * 
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
 * @return void
 */
public function setImage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image) {
    $this->image = $image;
}
```

and this simple fluid mark-up:

```
<f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'data.image'}" />
<f:form.upload property="image" />
```

so if try to submit the empty upload form I get the following error message, because the filereference is still null:

**Exception while property mapping at property path "":PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Data::setImage() must be an instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference, null given...**

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/

Comment: but in this example he validate just the filereference but not the upload input or am I wrong?

Comment: hm ok but if I modify this example and add @validate NotEmpty to protected $image then it works for this example :) ... I have to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I had an error in my model setter for the image property :O ... like pgampe said if you have trouble with fileupload take a look at this awesome example: github.com/helhum/upload_example and if you want to add validation on upload input just add a validate annotation to image property, it works like a charm :)

```
/**
 * image
 * 
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $image;
```

I have changed:

```
/**
 * Sets the image
 * 
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
 * @return void
 */
public function setImage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image) {
    $this->image = $image;
}}
```

to

```
/**
 * Sets the image
 * 
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
 * @return void
 */
public function setImage($image) {
    $this->image = $image;
}
```